# Passing JavaScript variables to PHP as a hidden input

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, hidden-field

I'm using CodeIgniter and in a single PHP file with JavaScript inside, I want to pass a JavaScript variable to the body (PHP) and make it a hidden input. But whenever I use the controller to post the value (where the JavaScript variable is), it returns none. Here are some parts of the code:

JS:

```
function pass() {
   //some code
   document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = yes; //where yes is a var
}
```

HTML (PHP):

```
<form action="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="yes" value="<?php $yes= "<p id='yes'> </p>"; echo $yes;?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Done" />
</form>
```

So whenever I post the `yes` in the controller `$yes = $this->input->post('yes');` it returns nothing.

How can I pass the JavaScript variable so I can use it again in the next file? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did'nt set the form method so it defaults to `GET`
You should set

```
<form action="search" method="POST">
```

try
**JS :**

```
var yes = "<?php echo $_POST['yes']; ?>";
document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = yes;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `submit` button and your `hidden` field have the same `name`
  **yes** .
- You try to access your `hidden` input by `id` yes , and your input
  does not have this id , use `getElementByName('yes')` instead or give
  your hidden field `id='yes'`.
- You use `innerHtml` which only sets or returns the inner HTML of an element,it should be `value`.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form action="search">
    <input id='yes' type="hidden" name="yes" value="<?php $yes= "<p id='yes'> </p>"; echo $yes;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="yess" value="Done" />
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
document.getElementById('yes').value = yes;//yes is a variable
```

Comment: I tried this but when I did `$yes= $this->input->post('yes');` to the controller and echo it, it displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `value` property of the `<input>`, not the `innerHTML`. You also need to give the `<input>` a different name than other fields or the "submit" button. Finally, you have to give your `<input>` an "id" property so that you can actually get it with `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the `value` of the hidden input, not the `innerHTML`. This code should work:

```
function pass() {
   //some code
   document.getElementById('yes').value = yes; //where yes is a var
}
```

Another problem, as noted by Pointy, is that the hidden input doesn't actually have an id, so you should give it an id (in this case the id should be `yes`).

Something you should also do is escape the html you are inserting into the hidden input with PHP, so it doesn't accidentally get parsed. You can do this with `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
<form action="search">
        <input type="hidden" id="yes" name="yes" value="<?php $yes= htmlspecialchars("<p id='yes'> </p>"); echo $yes;?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I did `$yes= $this->input->post('yes');` to the controller and echo it, it displays nothing.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is unrelated to the Javascript. If you replace the hidden input with just a normal text input, does it work then?

Comment: Yes, the value of the input is displayed in the textfield.